# Create collection of objects which has a property of type Collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following classes:

```
public class File
{     public string FileId; 
      public <Batch> Batches;
      public decimal Amount; 
}

public class Batch
{     public string FileId; 
      public string BatchCode;
      public decimal Amount; 
}
```

I want to create the following output object:

```
public class SummaryFile
{
   public List<File> Files;
}
```

Now I have the following list of the Batch class:

```
List<Batch> batches;
```

Now this list would look like the following:

```
batches[0] = new Batch{ FileId = 1, BatchCode = "A", Amount = 5 }; 
batches[1] = new Batch{ FileId = 1, BatchCode = "B", Amount = 10 }; 
batches[2] = new Batch{ FileId = 2, BatchCode = "C", Amount = 22 };
```

My output object is the following:

```
    public class SummaryFile
    {
       public List<File> Files;
    }
```

I would expect my output to look like the following:

```
    "Files": [
   {
      "FileId": "1",
      "Batches": [
    {
      "BatchCode": "A",
      "Amount": 5
    },
    {
      "BatchCode": "B",
      "Amount": 10
    }, 
  ],             
  "FileAmount": 15,
  },
 {
      "FileId": "2",
      "Batches": [
    {
      "BatchCode": "C",
      "Amount": 22
    },
 ],             
  "FileAmount": 22
 }
 ]
```

is it possible to accomplish this using Linq if not what is the best way to accomplish this? Coming from the mainframe I would use control break processing to accomplish this. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var summaryFile = new SummaryFile
{
    Files = batches.GroupBy(p => p.FileId)
                   .Select(p => new File
                   {
                       FileId = p.Key,
                       Batches = p.ToList(),
                       Amount = p.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                   }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: This has worked for me, thank you so much for the feedback.